# What is the character limit of full links (not shortened) created by twitter's t.co?

Tags: javascript, redirect, twitter, url-shortener

I understand there's no theoretical character limit to a URL, but it's 255 for the domain.

The consensus seems to indicate a safe bet is about 2000 characters, but it all [depends on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string) the browser and web server.

The [twitter API faq](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tco) for t.co doesn't mention a limit for expanded links, but instead only the shortened links.

I want to use javascript to store self-contained data in the URL, such as with parameters, for object properties that reference the data.

The data stored can be large, so I also want to compress the data so that it will fit in a URL string. This will also require encoding the compressed binary data into Base64 characters that are valid in a URL.

```
function compressAndEncode(content) {
    const compressed = compress(content);
    const encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(compressed)));
    const params = encodeURIComponent(encoded);
    
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    url.searchParams.set('file', params);
    history.pushState(null, '', url);

    const downloadLink = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
    downloadLink.href = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${encoded}`;
    downloadLink.download = 'compressed_file';
    downloadLink.style.display = 'block';
    downloadLink.textContent = 'Download Compressed File';
}
```

The code works fine, but there are limits, such as browser limits, and more specifically, twitter link limits for sharing on the platform, which uses it's own in-house link shortener, `t.co`.

Does anyone know what the maximum character count for a fully-expanded `t.co` link is, regardless of browser or target web server?

Is there a quick and easy way to check?

What happens if a link is too long?

Comment: The shortener expands the shortened url to the original full length one - at which point the browser behaves exactly as if you had not shortened it in the first place. The shortener is not something magic, it is basically simply a mapping of short to long url which is resolved once you visit the short one.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.

The t.co server must have a character limit for the original size URL. I want to know what that limit is.

Comment: Why would you think so? Why must it have a limit? You could just try shortening a url of a few different lengths to see how it behaves. Are you *actually* dealing with long URLs?

Comment: I think it would have a limit for basic security concerns - if it doesn't, it's a major security lapse on twitter's side - but this is not what I am asking, and I'm not here to debate that. Yes, I am dealing with long URLs, particularly with long parameters. I could try experimenting, but I don't want to trigger security mechanisms and risk getting banned, plus I thought someone might already have, or will have in the future, run into the same question, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: I am not aware of such a limit but I would be interested how this would remotely be a security lapse. You can shorten very long URLs - what does any security have to do with that. And I do not see why t.co limits matter here, chances are they are much higher than what your browser can handle anyway, therefore the limit would not matter because the link would break in your browser regardless.

Comment: Again, I'm not here to debate. My question relates to what the t.co limit is, not what a browser can currently handle.

Comment: the question was closed after someone answered it after about a year. there was debate in the comments (above) that was irrelevant to the question that i refused to participate in. i may have come off as rude unintentionally, but i'll leave my comments unedited. the question originally referenced the twitter api (javascript was implied) and so i edited the question with a javascript function that can potentially create very long urls - useful for anyone that wants to share long urls on twitter that are created with javascript, as was the case with my own javascript code prompting the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered after testing the boundaries of this using a URL with a dynamically generated query string in it that the t.co service seems to fail at exactly 4090 characters.

At 4089 characters my URL will consistently generate a valid card and allow posting, and at 4090 characters the tweet composer stops recognizing my URL, does not shorten it, and will not permit the tweet